# RISC-V program to compute arithmetic mean of 4 numbers

Tags: assembly, mean, division, signed, riscv

I want to compute the arithmetic mean of 4 signed integers in RISC-V. My current implementation is below:

```
.globl mean

.text
main:
    li a0 1
    li a1 2
    li a2 3
    li a3 4
    jal ra, mean

    addi a1, a0, 0
    addi a0, x0, 1
    ecall # Print Result

    addi a1, x0, '\n'
    addi a0, x0, 11
    ecall # Print newline

    addi a0, x0, 10
    ecall # Exit

mean:
   add a0 a0, a1
   add a1, a2, a3
   add a0, a0, a1
   srai a0, a0, 2
   ret
```

I think I am close but i am unsure if i used div correctly to divide the values. I also am not sure if I returned the mean correctly for a0 and if I need to free up space after.

I also need to round down any non-integer values that are computed by the mean, but I have no idea how to do so.

Comment: Have you tried assembling this, then running it?

Comment: Rounding down is automatic with integer division.  If you wanted decimals you'd have to use a different data type.

Comment: @ErikEidt it will not let me run because "register 4 is not recognized" when I try and divide by 4. I am not sure how to do that part of the mean formula

Comment: Right, so now you have the answer to the question you asked: you know for sure that you didn't use `div` correctly.

Comment: Load 4 as an immediate into a register, and use that register instead of 4.

Comment: If you were working in MIPS instead of RISC V, the assembler would have allowed that constant with `div`, by doing the load immediate into a register for you.  That however, requires a entire CPU register dedicated to such pseudo instruction expansion, which is rather a waste of hardware resources.  With RISC V, they have removed the practice of reserving a CPU register just for pseudo instruction expansion, so when it comes to these you have to do it yourself.

Comment: @ErikEidt: Or use a right-shift by 2, like a compiler would (https://godbolt.org/ has RISC-V gcc and clang; use `-O1` for a function that takes unsigned args)!  `div` is a terrible way to divide by 4.  Also, `jal ra, a0` is using `a0` as a jump target, isn't it?  Use a `ret` pseudo-instruction.

Comment: @PeterCordes, yes, that `jal` will not assemble.  It should be a `jalr` with `x0` for the return address capture, and `ra` for the branch target.  RISC V pretty much standardizes the pseudo instructions, so `ret` would be simpler (and it doesn't expand, just fills in `ra` and `x0` properly).  I took it somehow the OP wanted to use `div`, so I didn't suggest the shift, but that is good to note as I did forget to mention it.

Comment: @ErikEidt @PeterCordes I added a ```li``` statement to store the value 4 and then used it with ```div``` would this work to divide or should I try a right shift? Would that be a right-logical-shift?

Comment: Be experimental and give it a try!

Comment: @ErikEidt It is telling me that a0 is defined but never used but I don't see how that is true. How do I fix this warning?

Comment: @RiverJohnson: you should use a right shift; never use `div` to divide by a known constant power of 2.  Like Erik said, try it, and/or look at compiler output on https://godbolt.org/ for inspiration (use rv32 gcc or clang with `-Og` for a function that takes args and returns a value.  [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116))

Comment: a0 defined but never used?  That makes no sense, it's a register name.  Did you maybe mean it's used but not defined?  `jal ra, a0` is trying to use it as a branch target label (not register), I think.  If you need help with an error message, quote it exactly and say what source line it came from.

Comment: @PeterCordes my apologies, the exact error message is "label a0 is used but not defined". How would I fix this?

Comment: Try carefully rereading my comment.

Comment: @ErikEidt using ```jalr x0, ra``` does not work. I am told that jalr is expecting 3 arguments but only got 2. I tried ```jalr ra, x0``` as well but it didn't work. I am so confused how to return the mean value then. I tried using ```ret``` as a last resort and it also did not work.

Comment: When you're saying it doesn't work, you need to be more specific about the problem you're encountering.  Like `ret` for example -- what doesn't work??

Comment: Try `jalr x0, ra, 0` (or `jalr x0, 0(ra)` perhaps)

Comment: Use `ret` like a normal person.  If you can't use that pseudo-instruction, read the RISC-V manual where it explains exactly what `ret` is an alias for, and use that exactly.  Or use a disassembler on the machine code you get from assembling `ret`.

Comment: You return a value by having it in `a0` when you run a `ret` instruction.  The actual return only involves the program counter and return address.  It's calling convention is an agreement between caller and callee that the callee will leave a value in `a0`; you don't need to run any special instructions on it to make it the return value, that's just a software convention.